# Lenovo Yoga keyboard in tablet mode

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, tablet, sensors

Is it possible to prevent the notebook keyboard from being disabled on screen rotation (to tablet mode) in Lenovo Yoga series? So far I've only been able to dig to:

```
/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state
```

Which tells the system when the LID is closed, but does not relate to display rotation. The keyboard and the touchpad are disabled when the rotation exceeds 180°, but I was unable to find the sensor specified.

Nothing found in:

```
/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/
```

either.

Comment: you may find inspiration here:   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280217/why-is-my-laptops-keyboard-screwed-up-since-kernel-5-4-0-47-till-5-8-0-20    and her:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585681/ubuntu-20-04-upgrades-breaks-keyboard-mouse/763179#763179