# Why is my laptop's keyboard screwed up since kernel 5.4.0-47 till 5.8.0-20?

Tags: kernel, keyboard, kubuntu

My Kubuntu updated from kernel 5.4.0-42 to kernel 5.4.0-47 and my laptop's keyboard stops working (except brightness keys). Booting back to 5.4.0-42 solved the problem.

Keyboard also works perfectly on Windows 10 (I have dual boot).

Keyboard also works in GRUB (2.04). But it does not in kernels 5.4.0-47 and above.

Updating to Kubuntu 20.10 (beta) does not help either (kernel 5.8.0-20 same problem).

My problem is similar to this one: [Keyboard on HP notebook stops working under kernel 5.4.0-45-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271845/keyboard-on-hp-notebook-stops-working-under-kernel-5-4-0-45-generic)

And yes, I've seen this on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1894017

So what's the problem and why is it not fixed in whole range of kernels 5.4.0-47 - 5.8.0-20?

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *groovy gorilla* [20.10] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.10 is 22 October (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/groovy-gorilla-release-schedule/15531) when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: Think to answer the question you posed, the problem seems to limited to some HP and Acer laptops so far.  For me it started on 0-44 on an Acer.  Most of questions(less than a dozen) on here seem to be limited to those two makes.  Imagine the kernel writers and Intel would have to get together to find the bug on those models affected.

Comment: @guiverc this issue is valid for 20.04. I said about 20.10 just for reference that this issue is not fixed even in future release. The main problem seems to be in linux kernel module "intel_vbtn". After blacklising it everything works great

Comment: @crip659 yes, now I see. I thought it was only kernel problem. But seems like it's vendor-specific problem. Possibly because chipset is Intel Celeron N2940 (seems like mobile solution)

Comment: Ubuntu and Linux also had a kernel bug with Intel's baytrail CPUs.  Do not think they have completely fixed that yet, except for the work around with C-State.

Comment: @crip659 well that describes all - Intel Celeron N2940 is exactly Bay Trail. Can you point where can I find info about this kernel bug with C-State work around please?

Comment: The baytrail bug causes random hard freezes of the computer.  Do not know if they have fixed it yet.  You not knowing about it and having baytrail also, maybe is fixed.  I have the c state work around in grub(I think it is still there), so have not notice if fixed.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/883430/will-the-intel-bay-trail-cpu-problem-be-fixed-in-17-04/884128#884128

Comment: @crip659 yes, thank you, found info that it fixed. But sometimes my laptop catches freezes. but guess it's hardware because same happens on Windows10 too

Comment: I updated to 20.04 from 18.04 and I had the same issue with keyboard and mouse , I boot  in kernel mode form advanced settings to kernel 5.4.0-97 my chassis_type is 10 I created the blacklisted file for intel as mentioned and still the keyboard and mouse do not work after I enter my credentials at Ubuntu load. Can anyone help with a workaround ? I have a Huawei matebook pro

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution was found here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1894017

I just blacklisted `intel_vbtn` kernel module in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and rebooted. Author mentioned that somehow `intel_vbtn` thinks my laptop is in tablet mode (WHAT?!) and disabled keyboard/touchpad.

**How to blacklist**

To implement this, you can either create a new file in `/etc/modprobe.d` with the suffix `.conf` or use the main `blacklist.conf` file. The former may be preferable, since you can then just delete the file when it is no longer required (i.e. when the bug is fixed):

```
sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-intel_vbtn.conf
```

Add a line to the file, optionally with a comment explaining why you are doing this

```bsh
# bug in module breaks keyboard, so don't load it
blacklist intel_vbtn
```

Save the file, exit and reboot.

P.S. After mailing with Mr. Hans de Goede from RedHat I got following answer:

> This should be fixed by this upstream commit, which landed in Linus'
> tree a couple of hours ago:
> https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/platform/x86?id=8169bd3e6e193497cab781acddcff8fde5d0c416
>
> Igor, if you do:
>
> ```
> cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type
> ```
>
> On your laptop, and the output is **NOT "31" or "32"** then **this fix
> should work** for you.
>
> If the output actually is "31" or "32 (which I do not expect), then
> please let me know, because then we need a different fix.

P.P.S. On my system (Intel Celeron N2940) `chassis_type` returns `10`

Comment: Same issue here on Dell XPS 15 9500. Notebook is being detected with type 10. Your solution didn't work for me. Do you have any other workaround?

Comment: Which kernel version do you have?

Comment: Right now it is 5.8.0-48. I tested reverting to an old kernel (5.8.0-45). Same results. The strange thing that sometime after booting, I started to work with it using the trackpad and built-in keyboard then I tried the mouse by an impulse and it was working. My chassis type is being reported as 10 and I didn't revert the file that blacklists the intel_vbtn

Comment: Well, I'm now on the same kernel (5.8.0-48), and my chassis type is still reported as 10 but everything works as expected. Also intel_vbtn is still blacklisted. I guess you should create a report on launchpad for example. Also, did you remember which version update caused this issue for the first time? Maybe kernel commits inspection could help  us identify this problem

Comment: This is hard to say. It has happened during the time I was changing laptops. Before I was using an older version of XPS. This dates from 2 to 3 weeks ago. To be honest, keyboard and mouse work, and then sometimes they don't. This is pretty strange. Even the wired mouse was not working 2 days ago. These issues are annoying as hell. Dell has replaced the Home/End keys on this laptop, and which was another annoying step from dell, now external keyboard+mouse are not working properly.

Comment: This does not work for me. Laptop: Lenovo. I can't believe this nonsense... like wtf for real

Comment: Supposing the output IS "31" or "32" (as mine is) how do you fix the issue?

Comment: I updated to 20.04 from 18.04 and I had the same issue with keyboard and mouse , I boot in kernel mode form advanced settings to kernel 5.4.0-97 my chassis_type is 10 I created the blacklisted file for intel as mentioned and still the keyboard and mouse do not work after I enter my credentials at Ubuntu load. Can anyone help with a workaround ? I have a Huawei matebook pro. how come this bug is still here in 2022?

Comment: @curious try maybe **gregers** answer, maybe it helps you

Comment: @IGR94 true that worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be libinput that receives a `SW_TABLET_MODE` event from one of the laptops input devices. I don't know why they disable the keyboard and touchpad when receiving that event, but I would guess it was to avoid button presses on laptops you can flip the screen all the way around so the keyboard/touchpad is underneath the touch screen.

However, some laptop models emit this event even when the keyboard is not flipped around. Dell Precision 5760 has an "Intel HID switches" input device which triggers this event when the laptop is moved. So every time I triggered the accelerometer the internal keyboard and touchpad stopped working for some time. Before it went back to laptop mode. This bug seems to have been [fixed a few weeks ago][1], so hopefully it gets rolled out in a stable release soon.

Others have suggested blacklisting `intel_vbtn`, but that didn't work for me. Probably because of a different driver in use. But I found a different workaround, which is a solution in libinput for this exact problem; **register a quirk for the input device triggering tablet mode: `ModelTabletModeSwitchUnreliable`**.

First you need to figure out which input device is triggering the `SW_TABLET_MODE` event. Install libinput-tools to help you debug the problem:

```
$ sudo atp install libinput-tools
```

Now we need to record all input events with `sudo libinput debug-events`. Start it, and try to trigger the `SW_TABLET_MODE` event. It should look something like this:

```
-event27  SW_TABLET_MODE  .....
```

That means it is `/dev/input/event27` which is triggering the tablet mode. It is probably a different number for others. Let's list the input devices to find out it's name:

```
$ sudo libinput list-devices
```

Look for the event number you got earlier and note down the **device name**:

```
Device:           Intel HID switches
Kernel:           /dev/input/event27
```

Now we need some identifiers for your computers modalias:

```
$ cat /sys/class/dmi/id/modalias
dmi:bvnDellInc.:bvr1.4.1:bd09/08/2021:br1.4:svnDellInc.:pnPrecision5760:pvr:sku0A5E:rvnDellInc.:rn0FW9DW:rvrA00:cvnDellInc.:ct10:cvr:
```

It doesn't really matter what part of it you pick, but I chose `svnDellInc.:pnPrecision5760:` since it includes the manufacturer and model of my computer.

As root, create a file `/etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks`

```
[QUIRKS DESCRIPTION]
MatchName=*DEVICE NAME*
MatchDMIModalias=dmi:*PART OF MODALIAS*
ModelTabletModeSwitchUnreliable=1
```

For my Dell Precision 5760 it looks like this:

```
[Precision 5760 Disable Tablet Mode]
MatchName=*Intel HID switches*
MatchDMIModalias=dmi:*svnDellInc.:pnPrecision5760:*
ModelTabletModeSwitchUnreliable=1
```

Save the file. To verify the quirk matches the device, try:

```
$ libinput quirks list /dev/input/event27
```

It should output the `ModelTabletModeSwitchUnreliable` quirk.

Reboot your computer, and the `SW_TABLET_MODE` events should be ignored.

Comment: that worked for me even without being able to install libinput from recovery mode as networking was not available. I found the representative string from `$ cat /sys/class/dmi/id/modalias` and created the file `/etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks`. Couldn't check anything with libinput as i couldn't install it but after rebooting from normal mode all works!

Comment: I do have the same difficulty with a Laptop and  22.04 Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish (development branch): blacklisting intel_vbtn most times works (YEAH!!) as long as I use the gdm3 diaplay manager. Using sddm  leads to a completely disabled keyboard including on/off power switch (brand new Fujitsu E5511) but touchpad works. The challenge will be to resolve this (Kernel is 5.15.0-22-generic).