# Keyboard work for bios, grub, ubuntu live usb, but not the ubuntu 18.04 loaded on the computer

Tags: keyboard

The laptop keyboard works for everything except when the ubuntu 18.04 on the hard drive fully loads. It does not work for the user's password and it does not work for gnome. I tried installing xserver_xorg-input-all. I tried removing and installing xserver-xorg-input-all. I tried booting recovery, removing xserver-xorg-input-all, and installing it again.

In the bios the keyboard works. In grub the keyboard works. When I loaded ubuntu live from a usb drive the keyboard it works. But when I load ubuntu from the hard drive it does not work.

Comment: If using an Acer or HP and using kernel 5.4.0-44 or greater can see this question/answer.  Using something else then edit your question with details.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280217/why-my-laptops-keyboard-screwed-up-since-kernel-5-4-0-47-till-5-8-0-20

Comment: I followed that link, followed the instructions, and the problem was fixed. Though I booted to a recovery kernel to do it,

Answer (score 1):

following this suggested link I was able to fix the problem.

[Why my laptop's keyboard screwed up since kernel 5.4.0-47 till 5.8.0-20](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280217/why-my-laptops-keyboard-screwed-up-since-kernel-5-4-0-47-till-5-8-0-20)

By adding the line "blacklist intel_vbtn" to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf (I put it at the end.) prevents the kernel from thinking it is a tablet with an on screen keyboard.