# Kubuntu boots in to tty, Keyboard mouse not working when GUI started with startx

Tags: boot, kubuntu, python, mouse, touchpad

I've been using Kubuntu 18.04 for like a year now without any issues. However, when I started the computer today, it booted in to tty instead of GUI, then when I start the GUI with startx command, keyboard, touchpad or even usb mouse are not working.

What I did last was changing the default python from 2.7 to 3.7.

I cannot run any apt commands because the computer isn't connecting to the wifi while in tty.

I've tried booting with different kernels, 5.9.8, 5.4.0, 5.3.10, but all boots in to tty and keyboad, mouse don't work when GUI started with startx.

I tried [this fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280217/why-is-my-laptops-keyboard-screwed-up-since-kernel-5-4-0-47-till-5-8-0-20) too. But it didn't fix this issue.

Could you please help me fix this?

Thank you

Comment: That was a mistake to change default python. Now the system is broken.

Comment: Yeah :( i tried to change it back too. But couldn't since I cannot connect to internet

Comment: So u think the easiest way is a fresh install?

Comment: I set the default python back to 2.7 with `update-alternatives` command. But the issue persists :(