# Keyboard not working on Lenovo Laptop

Tags: boot, keyboard, lenovo

I'm a long-time Ubuntu user, and I took the occasion of changing the Linux distro alongside my daily driver. I went with the brand new Lenovo Yoga Slim Gen 7 Pro X equipped with R7 6800HS CPU.

While I was installing the 22.04 LTS, I faced a pretty serious issue: my keyboard is not working at all. To be clear, I'm sure it's not a hardware problem, it works like a charm in Windows, BIOS and grub, but as soon as the login screen pops out, only some of the function buttons keep working.

I also tried classic Ubuntu and some other distros, and they all came with the same problem, which is driving me crazy because none of the fixes I found and tried is working. I tried with the xserver-xorg reinstallation, and even with the grub thing of changing some of the i8042 parameters, but both of them seem to do nothing.\

I've reached Lenovo support but seems like they're washing their hands about the issue, although they claim themselves "Linux friendly".

Comment: I have the same problem on yoga 14s pro with R76800HS, A usb keyboard worked for this, but still couldn't boot the ubuntu 20.4 (unable to enter into graphic interface).

Answer (score 0):

[5.20 kernel includes a keyboard fix for ryzen 6000 laptops](https://lore.kernel.org/all/CAJZ5v0isLQVX3EqsokFthY5ka=V4Vse9T52s3EGSv41FKM1iGw@mail.gmail.com/), however until it's released I'm afraid the only workaround is to compile a patched kernel yourself. I can confirm applying the patch fixed the keyboard for me on PopOS 22.04.

In case targeted patching of your stable kernel is too much to ask you can try installing one of the [pre-built kernel packages](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) that already include the patch from Ubuntu Kernel Team. [6.0-rc7](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v6.0-rc7/) would be the best bet at the time of writing. Obviously this is a development version containing lots of changes so while it will fix your keyboard it may cause other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue - Yoga 7 with Ryzen 7 6800U, Kernel 6 is a working solution.
Don't panic, easy to install via https://9to5linux.com/how-to-install-linux-kernel-6-0-on-ubuntu-22-10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Nils  I got Lenovo with Intel i7 CPU and same issue, Linux Mint can't see devices keyboard.  Does it really have something to do with Ryzen ?

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

**Laptop keyboard and touchpad fail caused by "tablet-mode".**

Notebook, laptop, linux misconfiguration in distro Ubuntu and Fedora and
others for "tablet-mode".

**LUKS** can not be decrypted due to failing
keyboard.

Work around for Laptop Fujitsu Lifebook under linux are possible.

The issue about Keyboard and/or Touchpad not working is caused by "**tablet-mode**".

To analyze **events triggering** "tablet-mode"   (`sudo libinput debug-events`) see here, please:
[Why is my laptop's keyboard screwed up since kernel 5.4.0-47 till 5.8.0-20?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280217/why-is-my-laptops-keyboard-screwed-up-since-kernel-5-4-0-47-till-5-8-0-20)

I experience issues with several different Laptops Fujitsu Lifebook E Series (Fujitsu LIFEBOOK E4511, E5510, ...) Same issues with Dell, Sony, Lenovo, ...

I never managed to eliminate tablet mode completely.

I experience the same issue with Ubuntu and Fedora (recent versions).

I worked around the issue successfully. All Laptops I dealt with have circumvented  these (two different) issues.

Try solutions bit by bit, never as a watering can. Analyze.

*All information compiled from other sources. Thanks a lot to the people willing to share solutions and hints.*

In rare cases problem arises even when using USB-thumb-stick (this normally works fine - proof it is no systemic / unresolvable issue).

### keyboard

Missing keyboard is related to an early kernel module. Reason: The error occurs during boot process (long before X Window initialization): LUKS pwd can not be keyed in. Even function keys are "disconnected".

### touchpad

A touchpad not working has other reasons.

It seems to be the case, there are

- missing kernel modules or
- modules blocking functionality because they are active.

quick workaround for instant help:
If it is possible to reach X Window mode it often helps to close the lid and(!) wait until some sleep mode steped in. Waking up the laptop almost always activates keyboard and most times the touchpad.

### remediation or work around

One or a combination of these steps helped me to work around the issue:

- load hid modules
- block intel module
- block elan module
- install recent kernel
- grub process modules differently

Of course there are more ways to resolve it. Please document them in "comments" or your own contribution, please.

### **block intel module**

In

> /etc/modprobe.d/

create a new file:

> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-intel_vbtn.conf

with the following two lines in it:

```
# bug  in module breaks keyboard, so do not load it (askubuntu.com 127820)
blacklist intel_vbtn
```

### **block elan module (ELAN - touchpad)**

The elan_i2c module can block the keyboard in some cases of "tablet mode".
Block elan_i2c module in grub. Change

> /etc/default/grub

and set
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="initcall_blacklist=elants_i2c"`

(back up and eliminate all previous stuff between quotes)
and check for deviations in spelling of the module!

### **load hid modules**

This frequently helps with the touchpad.
For spontaneous remediation after successful boot invoke terminal and execute

```
sudo modprobe i2c-hid
sudo modprobe i2c-hid-acpi
```

To make your solution persistent amend or create file

> /etc/modules

Just add a comment and the two lines

```
i2c-hid
i2c-hid-acpi
```

More recent installations use location

> /etc/modules-load.d/

This helped with many touch pads like the „DesignWare“ Touchpad in a Lifebook E5511.
It is possible to use grub for this means:
`GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="i2c_hid"` (but failed for me)

### **grub process modules differently**

at least one case of "tablet mode" keyboard failure was avoided by reconfiguring modules in boot process using grub.
In grub (

> /etc/default/grub

) change line as

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

This may need combination with recent kernel installation.

### **install recent kernel**

in one case it helped to install a recent kernel.

Just take the latest stable one. This should do the job. Configure grub to support fallback mode etc.!
used source:

> https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/

FF!

PS: In grub always use

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY=false
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=false
```

to support analysis.

All information retrieved from other sources, thanks a lot to the people willing to share solutions and contribute help.