# Ubuntu 22.04.2LTS built-in keyboard not usable

Tags: 22.04

After installing Ubuntu and updating the dependency package, the built-in keyboard is not working, but the shortcut keys are working. I have tried to update the kernel, but still can't solve it, I hope you can provide a solution, thanks!

Comment: Does an external USB keyboard work?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Unfortunately there is no *actionable* data here, meaning that the only thing people can do is guess wildly about the issue. Could you [edit] your question to include the brand/model of your computer? With this, it will be easier to offer solutions that may solve your problem 

Comment: External USB keyboard is OK, my computer is MECHREVO jiaolong 16K code: GM5BG5E

Comment: maybe one of these can help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422266/keyboard-not-working-on-lenovo-laptop/1495081#1495081